# statistical analysis between two time series

Tags: r, correlation, matlab

I have two time series, which by looking at they appear to be correlated i.e. when one is high the other is high, and when one is low the other is low. Besides looking at the figure and saying these are correlated, I am looking for a statistical approach to assess whether these two time series are correlated or not. The image below shows the time series plotted against one another and a corresponding scatter plot. The data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/waggq7lub1pnlp7/test.txt).[image]

I work primarily in MatLab but also sometimes use R. If anyone could provide some support in either programs that would be great. I basically want to analyse what is the relationship between the 2 series and is the series greater during some stages compared to others, but I cannot determine which method is most suitable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transfer function modelling is a classic approach: you treat one series as an input, fit an ARIMA model to it, then examine the cross-correlation function of residuals from both series fit by the same model (prewhitened).
Box, Jenkins, & Reinsel (1994), _Time Series Analysis, Forecasting, & Control_;
Cryer & Chan (2008), _Time Series Analysis: With Applications in R_

Comment: The link to the data doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a newer method for analyzing time series and periodic data is wavelet coherence analysis which looks where 2 signals are both in phase and out of phase across time and frequency domains. It is different from the ARIMA models in that it gives only diagnostic information and nothing about mechanisms or forecasting.

There is a quite a bit of support for it in the Matlab I assume as this method is used mostly in physics and engineering but in R there is the Waveletco package that has an easy to use version.

Comment: I don't really know about using wavelet coherence. One of the vectors in the plot is an extracted scale from a continuous wavelet transform and the other vector is a measured series. Therefore I don't know if wavelet coherence is useful here.