# Capturing correlation failure between two time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, covariance, anomaly-detection

I have two time series as shown in the figure. The step curve in black is the trigger that causes the blue curve. As you can see first two peaks in both the series occur in the same time interval, however, the third peak on the blue curve does'nt seem to be caused by the step series in black. I need to capture such anomalous instances.

[image: comparing two time series]

I have tried doing co-variance analysis between the series; piece-wise, i.e. as the data is time aligned, I divide the series in several time intervals, and then check co-variance between the series at each time interval. Any low co-variance value indicates that the series are not much correlated in that particular interval.
I am not a statistician so I am not sure if this approach is right or if there are better and more efficient methods to achieve what I am after. The datasets I'm working with are huge (up to a couple of millions samples). 
Right now I am also trying wavelet coherence analysis on this as suggested in the post here -  [statistical analysis between two time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44874/statistical-analysis-between-two-time-series) 
Though I am not sure how I am supposed to interpret the results of the analysis to catch those anomalous time intervals. 
Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it always the case that your trigger signal is a series of positive  rectangular pulses? Do you have any model that predicts the blue given the black, such as a convolution kernel?

Comment: No I dont have any such model. These series are experimental data. For example, the step curve is the input pressure which is increased or decreased suddenly (manually), and the blue curve is the temperature (captured by a sensor) which increases or decreases based on the change in pressure. So basically I would like to know if the temperature is rising because of change in pressure or there is some other reason e.g. sensor fault, environmental, other inputs, etc. And yes, the input is always a rectangular pulse.

Comment: [Using correlation for time-series can be tricky.](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/06/correlation-coefficient-time-series-angel.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about to try (via m-regression!):
y(t+1)~b0+b1*y(t)+b2*x(t) or
dy~b0+b1*y(t)+b2*x(t) or
d2y~ ...
next just to explore resids,
or exclude t=6 & t=6.5 as out & try again...

Why "the step var" lost the odds counts???

imho you will get the results likes these:

```
y1  y1  y1  y1  -95.00% +95.00% y1
Param.  Std.Err  t      p    Cnf.Lmt    Cnf.Lmt Beta
```

Int.5.20    1.99    2.61    0.02    1.01    9.38

x   11.41   3.48    3.27    0.00    4.09    18.73   0.60

y   0.14    0.18    0.75    0.46    -0.25   0.53    0.14

out 4.65    4.23    1.10    0.29    -4.23   13.52   0.21

```
dy  dy  dy  dy  -95.00% +95.00% dy
Param.  Std.Err  t       p     Cnf.Lmt  Cnf.Lmt Beta (?)
```

Int 3.64    1.68    2.17    0.04    0.10    7.17

x   11.46   2.81    4.08    0.00    5.53    17.40   0.57

y   -0.67   0.16    -4.15   0.00    -1.00   -0.33   -0.58

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm sorry but I couldnt understand your solution. Is y(t+1) a lag ahead of y(t)? And how do you interpret solution from y and dy coefficients?